# How to use API resources in Laravel Inertia?

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 9, Jetstream, Inertia, Vue 3.

I have created an Api Resource for my Model Project

```
$projects = ProjectResource::collection(Project::get());

return Inertia::render('Project/Edit', compact('projects'));
```

In Vue, in the props "project" i get a nested array "data" and only the objects I need are already in it.

```
projects: Reactive
data:Array[2]
0:Object
1:Object
```

And it should be like this

```
projects:Reactive
0:Object
1:Object
```

I don't want to access props in vue via "projects.data"
I want it to be: "projects"
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the official laravel docs ([Data Wrapping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping))

> By default, your outermost resource is wrapped in a data key when the resource response is converted to JSON.

In order to turn off this behaviour:

> If you would like to disable the wrapping of the outermost resource, you should invoke the withoutWrapping method on the base Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource class.

So basically you need to run:

```php
JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
```

In the boot method of your AppServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and finally found a way to fix this on an ad-hoc basis. Set the wrapper to null after the resource class is created.  Working for me in laravel 9.

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail(10);
$commentData = new CommentResource($comment);
$commentData->wrap(null);
return Inertia::render('Comment/Show', [
    'myExtraPropDatum' => 'extra_data',
    'comment' => $commentData,
]);
```